# App crashes after a few seconds

Tags: objective-c

when i launch my app, on trying to do something, it will crash after a couple of seconds. I have warnings of warning: incorrect implementation of "downloadTextViewCOntroller. I also have "method definiton for -timerFinished not found and"method definiton for -timerFinished not found" this is my .m plese help me. the .h is also t the bottom

```
    //
    //  downloadTextViewController.m
   //  downloadText
//
//  Created by Declan Scott on 18/03/10.
//  Copyright __MyCompanyName__ 2010. All rights reserved.
//

    #import "downloadTextViewController.h"


@implementation downloadTextViewController

@synthesize start;

-(IBAction)tapit {
    start.hidden = YES;
}


-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    if (fabsf(acceleration.x) > 2.0 || fabsf(acceleration.y) >2.0 || fabsf(acceleration.z) > 2.0) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"This app was developed by Declan Scott and demonstrates NSURLConnection and NSMutableData" 
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}

- (NSString *) saveFilePath
{
    NSArray *pathArray =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    return [[pathArray objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedddata.plist"];

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:textView.text,nil];
    [values writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES];
    [values release];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIAccelerometer *accelerometer = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
    accelerometer.delegate = self;
    accelerometer.updateInterval = 1.0f/60.0f;
    NSString *myPath = [self saveFilePath];
    NSLog(myPath);
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath];

    if (fileExists)
    {

        NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
        textView.text = [values objectAtIndex:0];
        [values release];
    }

    // notification
    UIApplication *myApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    // add yourself to the dispatch table 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:) 
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification 
                                               object:myApp];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (IBAction)fetchData {

    loadingAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading…\n\n\n\n" message:nil
                                             delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel Timer" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [loadingAlert show];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    activityView.frame = CGRectMake(139.0f-18.0f, 60.0f, 37.0f, 37.0f);
    [loadingAlert addSubview:activityView];
    [activityView startAnimating];

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0f target:self selector:@selector(timerFinished) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];   


    NSURLRequest *downloadRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://simpsonatyapps.com/exampletext.txt"]
                                                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                 timeoutInterval:1.0];


    NSURLConnection *downloadConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:downloadRequest delegate:self];

    if (downloadConnection)
        downloadedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

    else {

        // Error
            }

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)downloadConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    [downloadedData appendData:data];

    NSString *file = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:downloadedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    textView.text = file;

    // get rid of alert     
        [loadingAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
        [loadingAlert release];

    /// add badge
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse {
    return nil;
}


@end

//
//  downloadTextViewController.h
//  downloadText
//
//  Created by Declan Scott on 18/03/10.
//  Copyright __MyCompanyName__ 2010. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface downloadTextViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
    NSMutableData *downloadedData;
    UIAlertView *loadingAlert;
    NSTimer *timer;
    IBOutlet UIButton *start;

}
- (IBAction)fetchData;
- (IBAction)tapIt;
- (void)timerFinished;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *start;

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't implemented your `-timerFinished` method declared in the header. In addition to declaring it in the header file, you need to provide the implementation of it, even if it's empty.

Your app is crashing because the timer fires after 10 seconds and it can't find the method it's trying to call.

Answer (score 0):

for one, you don't have anything for timerFinished, which is why you are getting that warning, but for now you can ignore it until you implement that in your code.  And you fire a timer and have it do something it can't, because you don't have the code in place.

To fix it, just put the following in your .m

```
-(void)timerFinished
{
}
```